# Is there a way to ignore the group in the Crystal Reports DistinctCount

Tags: crystal-reports

I have two tables, `Order` & `OrderSalesperson`. An `Order` can have 0 to n salespeople.

I have a report that is grouped by a) Salesperson and then b) OrderId (additional complexity removed).

I need to figure out how many Salespeople are assigned to an Order.

I tried the DistinctCount(OrderSalesperson.SalespersonId, Order.OrderId), but it only returns 1, even if there are multiple salespeople. It seems to be doing the DistinctCount on the group, not on the whole report.

Is there a way to have DistinctCount ignore the fact that it's within a group?

Comment: Are you using a relational (SQL) datasource, and if so, which RDBMS (SQLServer, Oracle, MySQL etc) is it?

Comment: I'm using SqlServer, but it's a 3rd party database so I can't make any DB changes.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this (a distinct count of all the Salespeople assigned to a specific order) inside Crystal, but you can do it inside your query - add the following item to your select clause:

```
count(distinct OrderSalesperson.SalespersonId) over (partition by Order.OrderId)
      as OrderSalespeople
```

- and add your new `OrderSalespeople` item to your report.